# Php Block İnclude File-Folder

Tags: php, security, include

Hi I have stracture like that;

- Project 1

  - Some Folter
  - İndex.php
- Project 2

  - Another Project Folter
  - İndex.php

Project 1 can include Project 2's file but I want to block that. To give an exmaple;

```php
// Project 1 -> index.php
<?php
include '../project2/index.php'
```

I want to block it. Projects can just include own files. How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want that? If you want these things to be separate, host the code in separate repositories and/or deploy on separate servers.

Comment: You can also run each PHP process with a worker bound to dedicated users for each site